# Why is find anchestor binding to attached property not working via value converter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a resource dictionary that contains icons as vector graphics. An attached property allows me to define the color of the icon. When i use the icons as static resource the binding from the resource dictionary to the color attached to the image is working. But when I use a binding with a value converter, the color binding is not working.

Does anyone know why?

Here the usage examples:

```
<!-- OK, smile is green -->
<Image Source="{StaticResource MaterialMood}" svg:Image.Brush="Green" />

<!-- Not OK, simle is black -->
<Image Source="{Binding Image,Converter={StaticResource GoogleMaterialSource}}" svg:Image.Brush="Green" />
```

ResourceDictionary.xaml:

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="MaterialMood" x:Shared="False">
  <DrawingImage.Drawing>
     <DrawingGroup>
        <DrawingGroup>
           <DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
              <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,24,24" />
           </DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
           <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding Path=(svg:Image.Brush),RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Image}},FallbackValue=Black}">
              <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                 <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="M11.99,2C6.47,2 2,6.48 2,12 2,17.52 6.47,22 11.99,22 17.52,22 22,17.52 22,12 22,6.48 17.52,2 11.99,2z M12,20C7.58,20 4,16.42 4,12 4,7.58 7.58,4 12,4 16.42,4 20,7.58 20,12 20,16.42 16.42,20 12,20z M15.5,11C16.33,11 17,10.33 17,9.5 17,8.67 16.33,8 15.5,8 14.67,8 14,8.67 14,9.5 14,10.33 14.67,11 15.5,11z M8.5,11C9.33,11 10,10.33 10,9.5 10,8.67 9.33,8 8.5,8 7.67,8 7,8.67 7,9.5 7,10.33 7.67,11 8.5,11z M12,17.5C14.33,17.5,16.31,16.04,17.11,14L6.89,14C7.69,16.04,9.67,17.5,12,17.5z" />
              </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
           </GeometryDrawing>
        </DrawingGroup>
     </DrawingGroup>
  </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

C#:

```
public enum MaterialImage
{
  Mood
}

public class GoogleMaterialSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
     if (value == null) return null;

     var imageName = string.Format("Material{0}", value);
     if (!Application.Current.Resources.Contains(imageName)) return null;

     var image = Application.Current.Resources[imageName] as DrawingImage;
     return image == null ? null : image.Clone(); // `x:Shared = false;` ???
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
     throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}

public static class Image
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty BrushProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
     "Brush",
     typeof(Brush),
     typeof(Image),
     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

  [TypeConverter(typeof(BrushConverter))]
  public static Brush GetBrush(DependencyObject element)
  {
     return (Brush)element.GetValue(Image.BrushProperty);
  }

  [TypeConverter(typeof(BrushConverter))]
  public static void SetBrush(DependencyObject element, Brush value)
  {
     element.SetValue(Image.BrushProperty, value);
  }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Image",
     typeof (MaterialImage), typeof (MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(MaterialImage.Mood));

  public MaterialImage Image
  {
     get { return (MaterialImage)this.GetValue(MainWindow.ImageProperty); }
     set { this.SetValue(MainWindow.ImageProperty, value); }
  }

  public MainWindow()
  {
     this.DataContext = this;
     this.InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```

Comment: I wonder how the attached property `Image.Brush` works here. There is nothing special about it, currently it can just store a value of `Brush` on a DependencyObject. But that's not enough to paint the image source in `Source` with the desired/specified Brush.

Comment: Image.Brush is only a kind of "backing store" for the color. It has not to paint anything. The brush of the icon get it's color from there via FindAnchestor binding.

Comment: where is Image property ? how is it exposed. (hint 1 )
do you have any binding errors (hint 2)

Comment: Imge property is places in codebehind of the mainwindow (`DependencyProperty.Register`) and it's working, the data context is correct. The static resource has no binding errors. the binding using IValueConverter has a binding error: 'Cannot find source for binding with reference `RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.Image', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=(0); DataItem=null; target element is 'GeometryDrawing' (HashCode=37895910); target property is 'Brush' (type 'Brush')`

Comment: this code `Application.Current.Resources[imageName]` means you place the `DrawingImage` in the application's Resources. Of course there won't be any Image control found upwards the visual tree. The code before worked because you placed the `DrawingImage` in the `Image.Resources` or some inner element's Resources so the `Binding` can find the Image successfully.

Comment: OK, this explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of King King I was able to change the code so it works now.
Instead of binding to the enum value with a IValueConverter is use now another attached property to set the image source:

XAML:

```
<Image svg:Image.Brush="Green" svg:Image.Source="{Binding Image}" />
```

CS:

```
public static class Image
{
  // color stuff goes here
  ... 

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Source", typeof(MaterialImage), typeof(Image), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(MaterialImage.Mood, OnSourceChangedCallback));

  public static MaterialImage GetSource(DependencyObject element) { return (MaterialImage)element.GetValue(Image.SourceProperty); }
  public static void SetSource(DependencyObject element, MaterialImage value) { element.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, value); }

  private static void OnSourceChangedCallback(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
  {
     var image = (System.Windows.Controls.Image)source;
     if (args.NewValue == null)
     {
        image.Source = null;
        return;
     }

     var resourceName = string.Format("Material{0}", args.NewValue);
     if (!Application.Current.Resources.Contains(resourceName))
     {
        image.Source = null;
        return;
     }

     image.Source = Application.Current.Resources[resourceName] as DrawingImage;
  }
}
```